# changing url of twiki

Tags: ubuntu, rewrite

I had installed the twiki.so my twiki is now accessible at http://mysite.com/docs/bin/view 
how can i make this url to http://mysite.com/docs/ so that it will access the same .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is the howto on what you are trying to do :

http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/ShorterUrlCookbook